# eclipse shortcut for "Toggle Link With Editor" not works on text editor

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I'm trying to setting my own shortcut for "Toggle Link With Editor" as ctrl+alt+shift+L(please notice the capture).. It works, but only the "Package Explorer Panel". When I press ctrl+alt+shift+L on the other panel, it doesn't work. What's the solution? Thank you in advance!!

[image]

Comment: What happens instead? Are you sure something else isn't already bound to two of those modifier keys and 'L'?

Comment: Nothing. It works only "Package Explorer Panel". When I press ctrl+alt+shift+L on java editor panel, it never works.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this only works when a view is active. What would this mean in an editor? You might have several views open which all support 'link with editor' so it would not know which to choose.